# unable to get file name in php / linux server

Tags: php, encode

currently, i am having a file with this name

```
14 BLAZE～Crimson Lotus～.mp3
```

on my linux server and by using glob() php function, i manage to loop out the file. But from var_dump info..the file name i am seeing is something like this

```
14 BLAZE��Crimson Lotus��.mp3
```

this issue also happens to my chinese/japanese file name as well..on server

```
7.浮生若水 (TVB劇集「太極」片尾.mp3
```

and from the var_dump

```
7.������ˮ (TVB������̫�O��Ƭβ.mp3
```

is there any way to display the filename originally on the web?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an encoding problem. Please check which encoding your filesystem is using, check your web page encoding and if necessary, try to recode the string:

- http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.recode.php

Comment: how to check my filesystem encoding? i guess i have to mail my hosting fellas on this checking? and for the recode part...not sure how to use it but followed by example seems like not working as well...for my webpage encoding is already set to utf-8 on the headers

Comment: Print the file names as hex code and compare the symbols with a character encoding table of e.g. UTF8. Ensure that UTF-8 is sent in the HTML header (not only HTTP), too: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding

Comment: seems like not easy to compare..not sure how to read those hex values